# How to run arcore android emulator in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, keyboard-shortcuts, augmented-reality, arcore

I have cloned the `Hello Sceneform` ARcore app and have imported it into Android Studio. I would like to run the app in the android emulator. I have setup the emulator for AR using the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator).

If I follow the same instructions in Windows, I can move the `virtual scene camera` using the `ALT` key (everything is working fine). When I start the emulator in Ubuntu and I start the app, the app starts and I get the message `Press Alt to move camera` in the status bar. But when I press `ALT` (plus WASDEQ keys to move around), nothing happens (meaning the camera doesnt move in the virtual scene).

I hope this issue is due to some special key preference given to `ALT` key in Ubuntu. Can someone help me in this regard?

Maybe tell me how to change the keyboard shortcuts for android emulator (maybe press some other button to move the camera in the virtualscene in the emulator) or how to disable that special key status to `ALT` in Ubuntu?

I have tried disabling all keyboard shortcuts in the `KEYBOARD` setting in Ubuntu but still camera doesnt move in the virtual scene when ALT is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Ubuntu Alt key is bind to many things, try pressing Alt and (Windows) - Super key at the same time.

Comment: Even Alt + Windows key is bound to something else (the icons on the sidebar in Ubuntu are given numbers from 0 - 9 when I press Alt + Windows key). It doesnt work. Any other option?

Answer (score 1):

> By default in [Android ARCore Emulator](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/emulator) you can use the following shortcuts:

**Move `left` and `right`**  ..................  press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

**Move `down` and `up`**  ........................  press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>

**Move `forward` and `back`**  ...............  press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>

**Change a device orientation**  ...........  press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and move a mouse

[image]

> This combinations work in `Windows`, `Linux` and `macOS`.
>
> ***If you have keyboard's shortcuts issues try to reconfigure your OS settings***.

Comment: I have questions in AR (AR beginner). I hope you can help me with that.  <br/>  1. Does Vuforia support Anchors like arcore? I want to develop an app where an image is displayed for two users and when one user adds AR effect to that image, its reflected onto the same image in other users' phones.
<br/>2. Does Vuforia have watermarks in the FREE version? I didnt get clear info regarding that in their docs.<br/>3. Which framework is better to start with? My target is Android.<br/>4. Any AR community where I can ask queries regard AR app development (being a beginner)?

Comment: 1. Does Vuforia support Anchors like arcore? I want to develop an app where an image is displayed for two users and when one user adds AR effect to that image, its reflected onto the same image in other users' phones.

Comment: 2. Does Vuforia have watermarks in the FREE version? I didnt get clear info regarding that in their docs.

Comment: 3. Which framework is better to start with? My target is Android.

Comment: 4. Any AR community where I can ask queries regard AR app development (being a beginner)?

Comment: 5. Is it possible to run the `augmented faces` sample app in arcore in an emulator? I tried but it didnt work. So, then, how to develop arcore apps if we dont have the supported phone ([list](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices))?

Comment: 6. In general, what is the best way to create AR models i.e. sbx files (like red nose in a human face when its actually looking normal)? Is it difficult or easy to develop those sbx models? Should I hire a guy to create a model for me? If so, can you tell me the platform to do so?